# python - Yahoo Finance API issues

Tags: python, api, rest, yahoo

I am trying to download stock data with yfinance, specifically:

```
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
yf.download('AAPL', start='2015-01-01', end=pd.to_datetime('today'), progress=False)
```

However, this returns:

> 1 Failed download:
> AAPL: TypeError("import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'")

If I try to print the data, it is an empty array.
I have also tried using the ticker class:

```
print(yf.Ticker('AAPL').info)
```

but this returns

> Exception: yfinance failed to decrypt Yahoo data response

Finally, I have tried yahooquery:

```
!pip install yahooquery
from yahooquery import Ticker

t = Ticker('AAPL', asynchronous=True)
print(t.history(period='ytd', interval='1d'))

print(t.asset_profile)
```

But this returns:

> Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [high, low, volume, open, close]
> Index: []
> {'APPL': 'No fundamentals data found for any of the
> summaryTypes=assetProfile'}

pandas datareader also does not work, though I believe it depends on yfinance. I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong, or if the yahoo api is down. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @DanielHao I tried it again, and the log said that all requirements were already sastified. Same issue.

Comment: it could be related to temporary problems with the Yahoo Finance API.  Maybe try later time.  I've similar experience too.

Comment: Just try again , it seems to be working fine now.  ```import yfinance as yf
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
print(ticker.history(period='ytd', interval='1d'))```

Comment: @DanielHao that returns: TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'. Maybe its not a yahoo issue, but a library issue?

Comment: Not sure your env.  but it's working in mine... (BTW - running in my IDE)

Comment: @DanielHao I am running this inside a Kaggle notebook, but the exact same script worked earlier today, with nothing changed.